# Is It A Good Idea or A Huge Mistake to Combine More Than 1 Type of Data Into A Single Column in An SQL Database Table?

Tags: sql, database

So, let's say I have 5 items, A, B, C, D and E. Item A comes in sizes 1 and 2, item B comes in sizes 2 and 3, C comes in 1 and 3, D comes in 1 and E comes in 3. Now, I am considering 2 table options, as follow:

Table 1

| Name | Size |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 3 |

Another option is Table 2, as follows:

| Name |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| B2 |
| B3 |
| C1 |
| C3 |
| D1 |
| E3 |

Now, which of these 2 tables is actually a better option? What are the advantages and disadvantages (if any) of each of the 2 tables above? One thing that I can think of is that, if I use table 1, I can easily extract all items by size, no matter what item I want. So, for instance, if I want to analyze this month's sales of items of size 1, it's easy to do it with Table 1. I can't seem to see the same advantage if I use table 2. What do you guys think? Please kindly enlighten me on this matter. Thank you in advance for your kind assistance, everyone. Cheers! :)

Comment: Option 2 makes no sense and will be difficult to manage.  You are not following normalization guidelines by basically concatenating data types into one column, so they do not serve one purpose anymore but multiple purposes.  Do not go with option 2 period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even understand why you have the second table option - what purpose does it have or how does it help you?  Plain and simple you have a one to many relationship.  That is an item comes in 1 or more different sizes.  You just saying that sentence should scream ONLY option 1.  Option 2 will make your life a living hell because you are going against normalization guidelines by taking 2 datatypes into 1, and it has no real benefit.

Option 1 says I have an item and it can have one or more sizes associated with it.

```
Item  Size
A      1
A      2
A      3
B      1
C      1
C      2
```

Then you can do simple queries like give me all items that have more then 1 size.  Give me any item that only has 1 size.  Give me all the sizes of item with item id A, etc.

Comment: Hi, this is also exactly what I think. However, the 2nd table option is actually a request made by the client. Strangely enough, even after I have explained to the client like you explained to me, the client still insists on the 2nd table option, which is why I am asking this question. Anyway, thank you for your kind answer. I will try to explain it to the client once more. Thank you again. :)

Comment: If the client hired you to make technical decisions why is the client making them?  The client pays for your expertise. Advise the client that you are following best practices and that you are doing the solution that is in their best interests.